# assembly return address not working

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this function in C:

```
int func(int n0, int n){
    if (n > 1){
        int nFinal = func(n0, --n);
        return (nFinal*nFinal) + n0;
    }
    return n0;
}
```

And want to to program it in Assembly.
I have this code:

```
    .data
    .text
    .globl  func
func:
    addi            $29,$29, -4
    sw      $ra,0($29)
    move            $8,$4       
    move            $9,$5       
    ble     $9,1,fim
    sub     $9,$9,1
    move            $5,$9
    jal     func
    move            $4,$11
    jal     quadrado
    add     $11,$2,$8
    j       fim
quadrado:
    mul     $2,$4,$4
    jr      $31
fim:    
    lw      $31,0($29)  
    move            $2,$11
    jr      $31
```

If the parameters passed in $4 and $5 are 2 and 1 respectively,  I can see that wen the program reaches the `ble` instruction it works as expected. It jumps to the `fim` label, restoring the return address from the stack and passing the return value to my `main` function.

The problem is that value on parameter $5 is undefined. It can be any given value. And I believe the problem with my program it's that the return address from my `main`function is lost and program can't return to it. I believe that wen program reaches the `jal func` instruction, the `main` return address its substituted by the `jal func` instruction return address.

How can I solve this problem? (Not asking code but just some directions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] And I believe the problem with my program it's that the return address from my `main` function is lost and program can't return to it. I believe that wen program reaches the `jal func` instruction, the `main` return address its substituted by the `jal func` instruction return address.

Pretty much.  You're decrementing the stack pointer (`$29` / `$sp`) at the start of your function to create space to save the return address (`$31` / `$ra`), but after reloading the return address at the end, you're missing the corresponding increment of the stack pointer -- you're looking at the value, but not actually popping it from the stack.

Comment: @MathewS Thanks. Added `addi $29,$29, 4` just before the `j fim` on my `func` and it's working as expected. Don't know if this is the right way but its working as it should :)

Comment: @Favolas: Even after adding that instruction, your program doesn't output the correct result in MARS.

Comment: @blackcompe you're right. Forgot to tell that changed ` ble     $9,1,fim`  to ` ble     $9,0,fim`. Offtopic using this code, how do you pass arguments in MARS?

Comment: @Favolas: I see. Do you mean pass arguments to a function? If so, just set $a0 and $a1.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting your code would help tremendously. Your use of temporary registers probably complicated things even more. You only need to use one temporary register. Here's a little help with the `func` routine. I assume you can complete the rest. And do remember to move the stack pointer when popping a return address.

```
func:
        #push rtn. addr. onto stk
        sw $ra, 0($sp)
        subi $sp, $sp, 4

        #result = arg0
        move $t0, $a0

        #if arg1 <= 1 return arg0           
        ble $a1, 1, rtn

        #call func(arg0, arg1-1)
        subi $a1, $a1, 1
        jal func

        #result = func(arg0, arg1-1)^2 + arg0
        mul $t0, $v0, $v0
        add $t0, $t0, $a0

rtn:
```

Comment: Thanks. I had my code commented but since it was on another language deleted before posting it on here. Relatively to passing arguments to a function on mars, was not talking on "force" setting $a0 and $a1 but using the "Program arguments provided to MIPS program" on the settings menu. Did't yet figure it out how does it work...

Comment: @Favolas: I've never used program arguments.